# Symfony2 DQL Select Sum of Grouped By on ManyToMany

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, 
       cl.id, 
       MONTHNAME(l.date) as month, 
       YEAR(l.date) as year, 
       SUM(l.hourlyPrice*(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(l.end, l.start)))/3600) as total 
FROM Lesson l LEFT JOIN l.students s 
JOIN s.client cl 
GROUP BY cl.id, month, year
```

The problem is that as every Lesson can have multiple Students, for each one associated it adds the Lesson Price (i.e. Lesson value is 100, with 1 Student it adds 100 but with 3 Students it adds 300 instead of 100), so I think I'm putting the DISTINCT in the wrong location. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Found this: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables. Very similar SQL example, but had no luck applying it.